# R: Loop to check if file exists and take it to a list #fail

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, filepath

I have 735 folders and some of them will have a .grd file inside, others won't.
After a lot of research here in stack, I came up with a code to check if the .grd file exists and, if it does, read the .grd into a list, if doesn't, skip it. But it isn't working... the code is resulting in a list with 735 objects, some of thm, empty. This is my code:

```
#the folder where all folders are
dir_maxent_spp<-"C:\\Users\\thai\\Documents\\ORCHIDACEAE\\Ecologicos\\w2\\SpDistModel\\Maxent_spp_20170815\\xm"

#list all folders within 
files <- list.files()

#create an empty list to receive the reads
grd_list<-list()

for (i in 1:length(files)){

#get into each folder
setwd(paste(dir_maxent_spp,"\\",files[i], sep="")) 

#set the name of the file I'm looking for
f <- paste0(paste(gsub('\\s+','_',files[i]),"_pred.grd", sep=""))

#check it's existence and it does exist, get it to the list
if (file.exists(f))
grd_list[[i]]<-stack(f)
}
```

Now, I do realize that the problem is this part: `grd_list[[i]]<-stack(f)` ... here I take the .grd into the i'th position of the list, right? But how do I skip a value for i without skipping the position in the list? I'm new to R, I'm sorry if the question is too naive

Comment: Why not let the `list.files` funciton do more work? see the `recursive` parameter.

Comment: you can also use 'grep(".grd", files)' to get the indicies.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the tips.. I didn't know those tools, I've learnt a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use another counter:

```
#the folder where all folders are
dir_maxent_spp<-"C:\\Users\\thai\\Documents\\ORCHIDACEAE\\Ecologicos\\w2\\SpDistModel\\Maxent_spp_20170815\\xm"

#list all folders within 
files <- list.files()

#create an empty list to receive the reads
grd_list<-list()

# Loop counter
j <- 1

for (i in files){
  #get into each folder
  setwd(paste(dir_maxent_spp,"\\",i, sep="")) 

  #set the name of the file I'm looking for
  f <- paste0(paste(gsub('\\s+','_',i),"_pred.grd", sep=""))

  #check it's existence and it does exist, get it to the list
  if (file.exists(f)) {
    # Store stack
    grd_list[[j]]<-stack(f)

    # Increment loop counter
    j <- j + 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `Reduce` your list, which would skip the empty rows

#### Reproducible example

```
grd_list<-list()

grd_list[[3]] <- 3
grd_list[[6]] <- 4

option <- Reduce(rbind, grd_list)
```

#### Output

```
     [,1]
[1,]    3
[2,]    4
```

Answer (score 0):

@Lyngbakr's answer got me to achieve a solution myself:

using

```
  grd_list[[(legth(grd_list)+1)]]<-stack(f)
```

instead of

```
  grd_list[[i]]<-stack(f)
```